# Gravitational waves veracity?

Tags: gravitational-waves, interferometry, ligo

W/r to the recent announcement of gravitational wave detection, since the signal to noise ration appears to be about 3 to 1 (not really very good) and there is no collaborating evidence from neutrino detection, why are people so certain that a gravitational wave was actually detected?

Comment: We wouldn't expect neutrino detection in the case of a black hole merger.  Plus two different detectors measured essentially the same signal shifted by a few ms. The signal to noise ratio doesn't have to be that good when you have two detectors.

Comment: Since when is it wild speculation to ask about S/N ratio?  I have also read that neutrinos are expected from BH mergers.

Comment: By the way I have a Ph.D. How can you possible judge that a person's knowledge of physics from a single question?

Comment: I just checked arXiv, since year 2000 about 73 article listed w/r to neutrino release from large body mergers. Some black holes, some neutron stars, some...

Comment: I can't find a single paper discussing neutrino release in a black hole - black hole merger.  I'm interested in that theorized mechanism so a link would be nice.

Comment: This link should get you to the arXiv documents http://arxiv.org/find/astro-ph/1/AND+abs:+AND+merger+AND+black+hole+abs:+neutrino/0/1/0/2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015/0/1?skip=0&query_id=a3c4032d9db878c3

Comment: I read through the titles of all 73 of those results and read the abstracts for a few.  I didn't see any about the merger of two black holes.  Most seem to be either neutron star - black hole mergers / accretion or neutron star - neutron star mergers.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102) the significance level was 5.1 sigma, which was good enough to claim a discovery by most scientific standards.